# Terraform state refactoring: Moving independent directories into parent module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have three pieces of architecture that I want to move into a model-like structure but I struggle to find a comprehensive piece of documentation explaining how to achieve that.

```
.
└── dev
    ├── backend.tf
    ├── main.tf
    ├── outputs.tf
    ├── variables.tf
    │
    ├── cluster
    │   ├── terraform.tfstate
    │   ├── backend.tf
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   ├── resource-efs.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
    │
    ├── db
    │   ├── terraform.tfstate
    │   ├── backend.tf
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
    │
    └── modules
        ├── cluster
        │   ├── backend.tf
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   ├── outputs.tf
        │   └── variables.tf
        ├── efs
        │   ├── backend.tf
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   └── variables.tf
        └── db
            ├── backend.tf
            ├── main.tf
            ├── outputs.tf
            └── variables.tf
```

I created the necessary links between resources and modular layout already however I now need to move the terraform states from the cluster and db folders into the modules folder. Also, I have a resource-efs.tf that I want to move to this modular structure.

I learnt that all initialised dirs in Terraform are modules, so I will refer to the `dev` folder here as my "root": currently cluster and db folders state have states that are stored remotely in two different folders, therefore I figured that I should be firstly initialising the `root` folder and then moving the states of the two stand-alone components - namely cluster and db - to the upper one, and into their respective modules.

I have tried terraform mv but got an error: what I did was to cd into the db folder and run

```
    terraform state mv -state-out=../modules/db/terraform.tfstate db module.db
```

And the error I got was

```
    Error moving state: Error parsing address 'db': invalid resource address "db"

    Please ensure your addresses and state paths are valid. No
    state was persisted. Your existing states are untouched.
```

Rightfully, since db is not a resource on its own, but the name of my future module.

From https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html they say that this command can "move data to a completely new state, it can also be used for refactoring one configuration into multiple separately managed Terraform configurations.", but I cannot figure how to do that - move entire modules that now are "root" modules on their own, to be; is there a way to reference the root module at all by doing something like `terraform state mv -state=db.tfstate -state-out=../cluster/cluster.tfstate module.root module.db`?